# Zipping folder with absolute path without keeping tree of folders

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, compression

I am attempting to use the `zip -r` command to zip a folder which includes two files. I need to pass the absolute path of the folder with two files `(/path/to/my/files/)`, which is causing all of the folders to be zipped with it, where as I only need the last folder `(files/)` and its contents to be zipped, so that when the file is unzipped, there is only one folder and the two files within it. How can I modify the command to be able to pass the absolute paths in the arguments while keeping only the last folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zip operates from the current working directory. If you have to return to the working directory you started from, that can work too.

Try:

```
cd /path/to/my
zip -r zipfile.zip files/
cd -
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be that simple :/

Comment: @Preston No problem, simple things can trip up anybody sometimes. It's not like the `zip -h` output is all that helpful to begin with.